# How can I fill in a drop-down-menu dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, drop-down-menu

I got some code (HTML and JavaScript) which creates a table with three columns and dynamic rows. I would like to have a drop-down-menu based on the entries of my first column. So the drop-down-menu should be filled after my table is completed. The first column can have multiple identical entries. So it is necessary to only show them once in my drop-down-menu.
At the moment I only have a static drop-down-menu. See code below. The Program is working for static drop-down-menu very well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <table id="myTable">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="150" style="background-color:red"></col>
            <col width="165"></col>
        </colgroup>
        <tr  style ="background-color:grey">
            <th>plane
                <select id="modelRangeDropdown" onchange="filterReports()">
                    <option selected="selected">All</option>
                    <option>number1</option>
                    <option>number2</option>                        
                </select>                   
            </th>   
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Secret</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="logstore/plane/trigger">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../Name"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="secret"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/../../../filterReports.js"></script>           
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What's the data source for that table?

Comment: The data comes from a java program. With the code above on "<xsl:for-each...> i'll get the dynamical data from the java program.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a sample of the XML data you get from the program please? Also, can you say if you are able to use XSLT 2.0 or 3.0? (I can see the stylesheet has version 1.0 specified, but if the solution involves getting distinct values, then it will be slightly easier with XSLT 2.0). Thanks!

Comment: Also, your XSLT stylesheet does seem to be missing a line. You have a closing `</xsl:template>` tag at the bottom, but no corresponding opening `<xsl:template match="..">` tag anywhere.

Comment: It seems from your question that you are trying some deduplication in order to build your menu. It's still not clear to me if the stylesheet is used in the context of server side (you metion "java program" as source of the input document) or client side (as expressed in the question). This will address some points made by TimC comment.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot publish the real data. I don't understand why it should be a benefit for you to see data. I have just three columns of e. g. a signal. Each signal has a name, a date and a secret number. How many signals will appear depends on the file the data comes from. But that doens't really matter for my problem.

Comment: I think I can update to xslt 2.0. Have to check it tomorrow. I copied the code from my file and obviously I did not copy the "match" line.

Comment: Okay so I try to explain it again: I got a Java file which reads data and making a xml file of all the data. The code above will take these data and make a html file with a table and drop down menu. The program above can already filter the name with the drop down menu (javascript not included here. Should I post it here?). Now I would like to fill my drop down menu not like above with <option...> but with dynamical entries which I get from the "name-column" of my filled table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could use XSLT 2.0, you could use `distinct-values` and write the `xsl:for-each` like so

```
<select id="modelRangeDropdown" onchange="filterReports()">
    <option selected="selected">All</option>
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(logstore/plane/Name)">
        <option value="{.}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </option>
    </xsl:for-each>
</select>
```

On the other hand, if you are restricted to XSLT 1.0, you would need to make use of a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). You would define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="planes" match="plane/Name" use="." />
```

Then, to get the distinct values, you would do this.....

```
<select id="modelRangeDropdown" onchange="filterReports()">
    <option selected="selected">All</option>
    <xsl:for-each select="logstore/plane/Name[generate-id() = generate-id(key('planes', .)[1])]">
        <option value="{.}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </option>
    </xsl:for-each>                    
</select>
```